Python data scrapping from Truecaller
I have a Python script to retrieve the names of phone numbers, but I am getting errors at the output.
Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Your API key from Truecaller
api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Path to the Excel file
excel_file_path = 'Ash.xlsx'

# Country Code
#country_code = 'GH'

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

# Assuming the phone numbers are in a column named 'PhoneNumber'
phone_numbers = df['PhoneNumber']

# URL for Truecaller API
url = 'https://api.truecaller.com/v1/search/+233'

# Create a new column for the names
df['Name'] = None

for index, number in phone_numbers.items():
    response = requests.get(url + str(number), headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        df.at[index, 'Name'] = data.get('name', 'Not Found')
    else:
        df.at[index, 'Name'] = 'Failed to Fetch'

# Save the updated DataFrame back to Excel
df.to_excel('updated_' + excel_file_path, index=False)

print("Finished updating the Excel file.")

And here is the error:
File "/Users/user/Desktop/Py/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 700, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.truecaller.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/search/+233540121351 (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x117708f70>: Failed to resolve 'api.truecaller.com' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")).


"Failed to resolve 'api.truecaller.com' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)" – your machine has trouble resolving the DNS name for api.truecaller.com.

By the way, if that's your actual API key, you'll want to revoke it now that you've published it to the internet.
